# how to use parameter to change scrollbar value in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

As u already know , The unity scrollbar value is between 0 to 1
I need a formula to change the value by the parameter I change in the inspector menu, like when I write 5 , the value changes to -5 to +5 , or when I write 10 the 0 to 1 changes to -10 to +10.
I created one but its not using parameter
`Left_Eng = 2.0f * (2.0f * ScrollbarL.value - 1.0f)`
the formula changes 0 1 to -2 , +2
If anyone have an idea please tell me
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to map the range `[0; 1]` to `[-x; x]`, right?

I think you basically already have it

- `[0;1]`
- `* 2` => `[0;2]`
- `- 1` => `[-1;1]`
- `* x` => `[-x;x]`

So together

```
var y = x * (2 * scrollValue - 1);
```